# Heroku redirect to my domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, heroku

How to do when im going to `www.myapp.herokuapp.com`

redirect me `to www.myapp.com`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy a domain from a domain registrar, which supports ALIAS domain record. If you have a domain already bought, just setup the alias for heroku. More descriptions you can read [on heroku site](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a redirect route for the heroku application - see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html